# Interact with express server with net server - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

so I have this idea in my head where when you run nodejs script it starts http(express) server on port 8080 and regular tcp(net) server on port 1337. And when you connect to tcp server via netcat and send "alert" it runs alert() command on webpage via javascript. Here is the code but the if statement is not working(it is printing data but not alerting on my web browser)

```
var app = require("express")();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
var net = require("net");

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

var server = net.createServer();

io.on("connection", function(sock) {
    console.log("Client connected");

    server.on("connection", function(conn) {
    var remoteAddress = conn.remoteAddress + ":" + conn.remotePort;
    console.log("New client: " + remoteAddress);

    conn.on("data", function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString())
        if (data.toString() == "alert") {
            console.log("YES ALERT");
            io.emit("HELLO");
        }
    });
    conn.once("close", function () {
        console.log(remoteAddress + " disconnected");
    });
    conn.on("error", function (error) {
        console.log(remoteAddress + " Error: " + error);
    });});
});

server.listen(1337, function() {
    console.log("Listening on 1337");
});

http.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Web server started on 8080");
});
```

Comment: what does console.log(data) shows?

Comment: data that i send over netcat

Comment: I mean what exactely does the console shows

Comment: console.log(data) shows this: <Buffer 61 64 73 0a>

Comment: console.log(data.toString()) shows the actual data

Comment: can you try data.toString('utf8') === 'alert' if it works?

Comment: It doesnt work, it just prints data..

Answer (score 0):

Include socket io client js in your webpage and connect to socket server

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:1337');
  socket.on('connect', function(){});
  socket.on('event', function(data){ alert(data.message)  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
</script>
```

you can Change the server side code, to emit the event to work with my example above.

```
io.emit("event",{"message":"HELLO"});
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. The socket.io is not listening on 1337 port, it listens on 8080